# Including Apache for Vagrant Will Not 'UP'

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant, berkshelf

So basically everything runs fine until I add:

`depends "apache2", "~> 1.6.0"` to my `metadata.rb`

and

`include_recipe "apache2"` to `recipes/default.rb`

and

this happens:

```
/Users/me/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday.rb:64:in `lookup_middleware': :json is not registered on Faraday::Response (RuntimeError)
from /Users/me/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/faraday-0.8.7/lib/faraday/builder.rb:146:in `use_symbol'
```

Has anyone run into this or even better resolved it?

I am trying to follow along with [this tutorial](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/03/24/getting-started-writing-chef-cookbooks-the-berkshelf-way/):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in a supporting library (Ridley) that Berkshelf 1.4.4 was tied to. It has since been resolved in Berkshelf 1.4.5.

You should uninstall and re-install vagrant-berkshelf to receive the updates. This can be accomplished by running:

$ vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-berkshelf
  $ vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf

Of course, this will also be resolved once vagrant-berkshelf is updated for Berkshelf 2.0.

If you run into a bug like this feel free to post it on the issue tracker on the Berkshelf or Vagrant-Berkshelf projects. It'll get the attention it deserves and a quick answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found reason, but unfortunately it seems there's no fix until vagrant-berkshelf uses berkshelf-2.0.x:

- https://github.com/RiotGames/berkshelf/pull/581
- https://github.com/RiotGames/vagrant-berkshelf/issues/54